# .net core webhook post dynamic json binding

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

I am integrating ESignGenie WebHook , I get different kind of json on same route.
How can I handle different kind of json request on same route.
Json request changes based on root object eventName.

```
{
    "event_name": "folder_signed"
}
```

There are 6 different events.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using WebApp.Enum;
using WebApp.Models;

namespace WebApp.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("ESignGenie")]
    public class ESignGenieController : Controller
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Callback for ESignGenie
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="model"></param>
        /// <returns>A newly created TodoItem</returns>
        /// <response code="299"></response>
        /// <response code="400"></response>            
        [HttpPost("webHook/Callback")]
        [ProducesResponseType(299)]
        [ProducesResponseType(400)]
        public IActionResult Callback([FromBody] ESignGenieWebhookResponseModel model)
        {
            switch (model.EventName)
            {
                case nameof(ESignGenieStatus.folder_cancelled):
                    break;
                case nameof(ESignGenieStatus.folder_deleted):
                    break;
                case nameof(ESignGenieStatus.folder_executed):
                    break;
                case nameof(ESignGenieStatus.folder_sent):
                    break;
                case nameof(ESignGenieStatus.folder_signed):
                    // Handle Signed
                    break;
                case nameof(ESignGenieStatus.folder_viewed):
                    break;
            }
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I have only made mapping of folder_signed event